# VBS process memory consumption growing over time

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I have a VBScript that I run with Windows Script Host.  The script reads some stuff from a text file and then launches a desktop shortcut every time a file is added to a certain folder.  It starts of at 1.4Mb memory and grows every time I add a file to that folder.  Is there a way to solve that?  If not, I guess I could have a script that periodically kills the first script and relaunches it?  Here is the script:

```
'- Read some stuff from a file
Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\Post 
Processing Files\Common Files\New Data Folder Watcher\DATA_STORE.txt", 1)
dataStore = replace(f.ReadLine,"Title:","")
f.SkipLine
shortCut = replace(f.ReadLine,"Title:","")
f.Close

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "
{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM 
__InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE "  & "Targetinstance ISA 
'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " & 
"'Win32_Directory.Name=" &Chr(34)&  dataStore  &Chr(34)& "'")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'- Watch
Do

    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent

    objShell.Run shortCut

    '- Delay
    WScript.Sleep 120000

Loop
```

EDIT: Added Set object = Nothing.  Process is still growing (a little less though).  What else can possibly make it grow?
New code:

```
'- Read some stuff from a file
Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\Post 
Processing Files\Common Files\New Data Folder Watcher\DATA_STORE.txt", 1)
dataStore = replace(f.ReadLine,"Title:","")
f.SkipLine
shortCut = replace(f.ReadLine,"Title:","")

f.Close
Set f = Nothing

strComputer = "."


' LOOP THROUGH EACH NEWLY ADDED FILE
Do

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE "  & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" &Chr(34)&  dataStore  &Chr(34)& "'")
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent

    objShell.Run shortCut 

    '- Delay
    WScript.Sleep 120000

    '- Clear Memory
    Set  objLatestEvent = Nothing
    Set  objShell = Nothing
    Set  colMonitoredEvents = Nothing
    Set  objWMIService = Nothing


Loop
```

Comment: Most likely it's because you're not clearing out all of your object variables. When you set an object to something, you have to set it to "Nothing" when you are done or it will remain in your system memory. Try adding these after your `Do..Loop`: `Set f = Nothing`, `Set objWMIService = Nothing`, `Set colMonitoredEvents = Nothing`, `Set objShell = Nothing`, and `Set objLatestEvent = Nothing`. You may want to restart your computer before running the script again to clear your system memory.

Comment: The DO LOOP is supposed to run forever... I set everything to Nothing in the end of the loop, but my process still grows every time a file is added.  Any ideas of how this is possible conceptually?  I added the new code above...

Comment: You are repetitively setting your objects within the loop. Do your initial sets BEFORE the loop, then set them to Nothing AFTER the loop.